# ¿Cómo detectar segundos?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que el usuario abre un `div` con cierta `ID`, el div tendrá un `button disabled`, que al estar 10 segundos ahí le quitaría la propiedad `disabled`, pero... ¿cómo sé cuántos segundos han pasado?

```
(function(){
  var contador = 0;

  document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click',
    function(){
      if (contador === 2){
        setTimeout(function(){play.disabled = true;}, 10000)

        contador = 0;
      }

      else{
        contador++;
      }
    });
})();
```

<sub>sin jquery porfavor</sub>

Me gustaría saber si el código esta defectuoso o existen mejores formas.

Comment: en tu codigo tienes  que se deshabilite. (`play.disabled = true`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa un [`setTimeOut`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) para ello

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
     // Aqui quitar el disabled 
 }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Para ejecutar código con un temporizador el objeto window cuenta con dos métodos:

- setTimeout: que permite ejecutar una función una vez transcurridos un determinado número de milisegundos
- setInterval: que permite ejecutar una función repetidamente con el intervalo de milisegundos establecidos

También tienes disponibles los métodos clearTimeout y clearInterval que permiten anular la ejecución diferida.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo utilizando cada uno de ellos:

```js
var boton1 = document.getElementById('boton1');
var boton2 = document.getElementById('boton2');

setTimeout(function(){ boton1.disabled = false; }, 10000);

(function(){
  var cont = 0;
  var inter = setInterval(function(){
    cont++;
    boton2.innerText = cont.toString();
    if (cont === 10){
      boton2.disabled = false;
      clearInterval(inter);
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<button disabled id="boton1">Botón 1</button>
<button disabled id="boton2">Botón 2</button>
```